# I want to convert the below code to a lambda expression so that i can remove ugly for loops

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to convert the below code to a lambda expression

```
for (int i=0; i < commentsCount ;i++) {
    System.out.println(js1.getInt("fields.comment.comments[" + i + "].id"));
}
```

Comment: Use IntelliJ Idea, it auto converts simple loops to streams. Also, why are loops ugly? I do not see anything ugly in this loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using an `IntStream` here along with a lambda to build each string expression to be printed:

```
IntStream.range(0, commentsCount)
    .map(i -> js1.getInt("fields.comment.comments[" + i + "].id"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```